# Compiling phalcon - needs 2GB, I have 0.5GB, is there a workaround for the small vps?

Tags: phalcon

As subject - I have a 500MB vps with Centos 7, I want to put phalcon on it for its low resource demands. But it needs 2GB to compile. I can't increase any storage. Is there a workaround?

Comment: Um... How would you expect to workaround having only 25% of the memory required? *I have to carry a single block of stone that measures 10 feet by 10 feet by 10 feet, but my car is a SUV. How do I fit that stone in my car?*

Comment: How about compiling the source on another CentOS 7 with bigger capacities (e.g. inside a VM) and then copying the resulting binary in your VPS ?

Answer (score 1):

You have 500MB of storage? Or perhaps did you mean 500Mb of memory?
I already had the same problem with memory, so what I did was creating a temporary swap ram to compile phalcon:

*running as root*

```
/bin/dd if=/dev/zero of=/var/swap.1 bs=1M count=5120
chmod 600 /var/swap.1
/sbin/mkswap /var/swap.1
/sbin/swapon /var/swap.1

cd /tmp
git clone https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon
cd cphalcon/build
sudo ./install

/sbin/swapoff /var/swap.1
rm -rf /var/swap.1
```

Hope it helps ;)